# create a class attribute without going through __setattr__

Tags: python, class, setattr

What I have below is a class I made to easily store a bunch of data as attributes.
They wind up getting stored in a dictionary.
I override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` to store and retrieve the values back in different types of units.
When I started overriding `__setattr__` I was having trouble creating that initial dicionary in the 2nd line of `__init__` like so...

`super(MyDataFile, self).__setattr__('_data', {})`

**My question...**
Is there an easier way to create a class level attribute with going through `__setattr__`?
Also, should I be concerned about keeping a separate dictionary or should I just store everything in `self.__dict__`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from unitconverter import convert
import re

special_attribute_re = re.compile(r'(.+)__(.+)')

class MyDataFile(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyDataFile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        super(MyDataFile, self).__setattr__('_data', {})

    #
    # For attribute type access
    #
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._data[name] = value

    def __getattr__(self, name):

        if name in self._data:
            return self._data[name]

        match = special_attribute_re.match(name)
        if match:
            varname, units = match.groups()
            if varname in self._data:
                return self.getvaras(varname, units)

        raise AttributeError

    #
    # other methods
    #
    def getvaras(self, name, units):
        from_val, from_units = self._data[name]
        if from_units == units:
            return from_val
        return convert(from_val, from_units, units), units

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._data)



d = MyDataFile()

print d

# set like a dictionary or an attribute
d.XYZ = 12.34, 'in'
d.ABC = 76.54, 'ft'

# get it back like a dictionary or an attribute
print d.XYZ
print d.ABC

# get conversions using getvaras or using a specially formed attribute
print d.getvaras('ABC', 'cm')
print d.XYZ__mm
```

Comment: Did you try it without `__setattr__`?  If so, what did you observe?  It should work fine.

Comment: I need __setattr__ because I want to set the variables with units in a similar way that I'm getting them back.  I just didn't have that in the copy that I pasted.

For example either `d.XYZ = 12.34, 'in'` or `d.XYZ__in = 12.34`

Comment: Your `__setattr__` in the example doesn't *do* anything.  Remove it.  Try without it.  See what happens.  Store your value and units as a simple 2-tuple.  Since the `__setattr__` you provided *is* the default implementation, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `__setattr__` in the example doesn't *do* anything except put things in `_data` instead of `__dict__`  Remove it.

Change your `__getattr__` to use `__dict__`.

Store your value and units as a simple 2-tuple.